# Realtek HD Audio Drivers disappeared

Tags: windows-10, drivers, realtek-hd-audio

Suddenly my Realtek HD Audio Driver disappeared. I am sure I had it and some days ago I realized that I don't have realtek anymore.

[image]

Should I download realtek drivers again? How do I know which driver I need to download?

Also for some reason I can't use my microphone. I plugged it in almost every USB port for microphone but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should go to your system manufacturer website and download the latest drivers for your audio device.

While there you should probably check for any firmware updates and BIOS.

Comment: Fine advice - but I have sometimes found that drivers directly from Realtek have performed 'better' & restore the full 5.1 parameters panel that is sometimes missing in the OEM driver package. Get the [High Definition Audio Codecs (Software)](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/) It may ask you to agree before you can get to that page.

Comment: Yes, if getting the OEM drivers doesn't work, going to the manufacturer can be a good second step. OEM sites tend to be easier to deal with, for the most part, as they'll have all drivers available, not just the sound device drivers, and the fact there was no "unknown devices" listed in the screenshot meant there was a chance there was a deeper issue. If OP had to call support, they'd be able to say they got the drivers the OEM determined are the best for their system.

Comment: I've known the NVidia drivers to overwrite the 'proper' ones. It's an issue we've been seeing in an online game I help support.